# Flag yb_enable_read_committed_isolation not working in YugabyteDB 2.15.0.0

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

With 2.15.0.0 `yb_enable_read_committed_isolation` flag doesn’t seem to work anymore? This was working with 2.13:

```
ERROR: unknown command line flag '--yb_enable_read_committed_isolation'
```

I’m running yugabyted with:

```
/yugabyte/bin/yugabyted start --daemon=false --ui=false --initial_scripts_dir=/init-scripts --tserver_flags="--yb_enable_read_committed_isolation=true"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s a tserver gflag, so that should be `--tserver_flags="--yb_enable_read_committed_isolation=true"` and it will work.